# Как из количественной переменной сделать номинальную

Tags: python

Допустим, что есть массив наблюдений, в котором одна из переменных принимает случайные значения от 1 до 100. Как из последней сделать порядковую переменную, которая бы принимала значения в зависимости от заданных порогов (например: "1" если  <50; "2" если [50,60]; иначе "3")?
Хотел использовать map или лямбда-функцию, но не удалось :С

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [123]: lst
Out[123]: [87, 92, 22, 1, 94, 18, 92, 44, 77, 73, 53, 24, 9, 67, 20]

In [142]: res = ["1" if x < 50 else "2" if x <= 60 else "3" for x in lst]

In [143]: res
Out[143]: ['3', '3', '1', '1', '3', '1', '3', '1', '3', '3', '2', '1', '1', '3', '1']
```

Для больших объемов данных лучше воспользоваться Numpy или Pandas - они работают значительно быстрее:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np   # для генерации случайных чисел
```

Пример данных на входе:

```
In [166]: df = pd.DataFrame({'var':np.random.randint(1, 101, 10)})

In [167]: df
Out[167]:
   var
0   38
1  100
2   74
3    5
4   66
5   32
6   91
7    6
8   68
9   50
```

воспользуемся [pd.cut()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html):

```
In [168]: df['tag1'] = pd.cut(df['var'], bins=[0,50,60,101], labels=[1,2,3])

In [169]: df['tag2'] = pd.cut(df['var'], bins=[0,50,60,101])
```

Результат: - если не указать значения для параметра `labels` [pd.cut()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) сам сконструирует диапазоны значений - это может пригодится:

```
In [170]: df
Out[170]:
   var tag1       tag2
0   38    1    (0, 50]
1  100    3  (60, 101]
2   74    3  (60, 101]
3    5    1    (0, 50]
4   66    3  (60, 101]
5   32    1    (0, 50]
6   91    3  (60, 101]
7    6    1    (0, 50]
8   68    3  (60, 101]
9   50    1    (0, 50]
```

также можно включить левые границы диапазонов вместо правых:

```
In [172]: df['tag3'] = pd.cut(df['var'], bins=[0,50,60,101], right=False)

In [173]: df
Out[173]:
   var tag1       tag2       tag3
0   38    1    (0, 50]    [0, 50)
1  100    3  (60, 101]  [60, 101)
2   74    3  (60, 101]  [60, 101)
3    5    1    (0, 50]    [0, 50)
4   66    3  (60, 101]  [60, 101)
5   32    1    (0, 50]    [0, 50)
6   91    3  (60, 101]  [60, 101)
7    6    1    (0, 50]    [0, 50)
8   68    3  (60, 101]  [60, 101)
9   50    1    (0, 50]   [50, 60)
```

Comment: Проверка `50 <=` избыточна, без нее тоже будет работать.

Comment: @insolor, спасибо! исправил...

Answer (score 3):

Как раз есть [`numpy.digitize()` функция](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html), которая возвращает номера диапазонов, к которым принадлежат элементы массива:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.random.randint(1, 101, size=10)
>>> a
array([16, 42, 19, 88, 69, 15,  5,  1, 33, 50])
>>> np.digitize(a, [1, 50, 60, 101])
array([1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2])
```

- `1 <= 16 < 50` поэтому номер диапазона для `16` равен `1`
- `50 <= 50 < 60` поэтому номер диапазона для `50` равен `2`
- `60 <= 88 < 101` поэтому номер диапазона для `88` равен `3`

Comment: @MaxU: я думаю автор просто не знаком с обозначениями: `[50, 60)` К примеру, нет упоминания в вопросе о *"от 1 до 100"* *включительно* или нет. Поэтому я явно диапазоны указал, чтобы не было разночтений. Если необходимо, можно `61` вместо `60` написать.